# Ohm (omega) character not showing in Flash Player

Tags: fonts, actionscript-2, flash-cs5

I have embedded the font. I'm creating a TextField in ActionScript and have set embed fonts to true. I'm referencing the name correctly. I have tried adding the Character range and adding the character into the "include these characters" box.

No matter, what I try I can't add the Ohm (omega) character. In addition, I have tried Googling but only provides suggestions to do what I have already done. I'm using ActionScript 2.0 with Flash CS5.

[image]

Comment: Have you verified the Ω glyph is included in Futura Md BT?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the issue after much debugging. I imported the data from xml file. The character in the xml file was not the standard unicode Ω glyph and was the old Ohm symbol. After going to Wikipedia and copying the Ω capital omega symbol replacing the one in the xml file and the one in Flash "Also include these characters" I was able to get it to work.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega